# How to use noVNC to connect to a VNC server through browser

Tags: websocket, vnc

I am trying to install novnc on CentOS. My default repositories doesn't have novnc listed in them hence says

```
"-bash-3.2# yum install novnc
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.lga7.us.voxel.net
 * extras: mirror.rackspace.com
 * rpmforge: mirror.us.leaseweb.net
 * updates: mirror.atlanticmetro.net
Setting up Install Process
No package novnc available.
Nothing to do"
```

If anyone knows any repository that has noVnc, please share. Direct copy of the zip from the [project source](https://github.com/kanaka/noVNC) and trying to start the websockify gave me following error

> ./websockify --web ./ 5802 localhost:5901 WARNING: no 'numpy' module,
>   HyBi protocol is slower or disabled WARNING: no 'ssl' module,
>   TLS/SSL/wss is slower or disabled WARNING: no 'multiprocessing'
>   module, Multi-Processing is slower or disabled Traceback (most recent
>   call last):   File "./websockify", line 18, in ?
>       except: from urlparse import parse_qs, urlparse ImportError: cannot import name parse_qs

All I am trying to do is connect to the vnc through browser directly. Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just merge a fix from websockify to the noVNC repo. This should fix a bug with when running websockify with python2.4. Please download and try again.

Note that this also means that have a really old distribution of CentOS so some of the websockify functionality will be limited (single client at a time, slower binary socket support, and no SSL support.